# PHP SSH Lib, echoing to a file

Tags: php, encoding, ssh, escaping, phpseclib

I'm trying to create a PHP script that creates a file on a remote linux server through ssh, and echos the file contents into it.

However, I cannot figure out how to correctly and safely encode/escape the file contents, so that the contents don't get interpreted as commands.

I'm using phpseclib from [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

I've tried something like

```
echo $ssh->exec('sudo echo "' . escapeshellarg($newConfig) . '" > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf') . "\n";
```

but without success.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: after your question, I went to the phpseclib page and tried to learn it.but I have a problem to ask it for you :) . dont you get the error cannot connect to host ... or something ?

Comment: I've already connected to the host in previous steps using

`$ssh = new Net_SSH2($url);
      if (!$ssh->login('username', $sshkey)) {
        echo 'Login Failed';
      } else {
        echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about this all wrong, I should have used `Net_SFTP` instead of `NET_SSH` for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

What about [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)? Quoting the description of that vs escapeshellarg:

> escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes
>   any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a
>   shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument.

...and...

> escapeshellcmd() escapes any characters in a string that might be used
>   to trick a shell command into executing arbitrary commands. This
>   function should be used to make sure that any data coming from user
>   input is escaped before this data is passed to the exec() or system()
>   functions, or to the backtick operator.
>
> Following characters are preceded by a backslash: #&;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$\,
>   \x0A and \xFF. ' and " are escaped only if they are not paired. In
>   Windows, all these characters plus % are replaced by a space instead.

Comment: This sort of works. The content doesn't try to execute, but its saving all the escaping to the file itself now, so the config is invalid. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you download the *.conf file you created with that command via SFTP and compare it to what it should be? I assume you're using SSH to create it because, although it's permissions allow it to be read, they don't allow it to be written to without the use of sudo?

Comment: Yeah thats right. As a workaround, I've used SSH to change the permissions, SFTP to write the file, and then changed the permissions back again with SSH.

Comment: That works. Although it'd still be interesting to know what was different in the file idk lol.

Comment: All the config was escaped in the file itself. E.g. each line started with a `^`, and instead of `'` quotes, it had more of these `^`